# "Charade" -- missing stamps

Tags: plot-explanation, charade

In "Charade", Jean-Louis runs off to the stamp dealer with the stamps Reggie has given him. Do we actually see Reggie (Audrey Hepburn) give the stamps to Jean-Louis?

Answer (score 2):

We don't.  We just see James Coburn discovering that the stamps have been torn from the envelope. He then tells Cary Grant (and the audience) that Reggie knows their value and has double-crossed them all.  It is one of many instances of the audience being led to believe something that isn't true.  From [the script](https://sfy.ru/?script=charade):

> 347. ANOTHER ANGLE Including ADAM as he enters, his gun trained on TEX.  Without speaking he goes to the airlines bag, then stoops down
>        to go through the spilled contents, keeping one eye all the time on
>        TEX.  But he can't find what he's looking for.
>
>      ```
>        ADAM (quietly)      All right -- where's the letter? 
>
>        TEX     The letter?  The letter ain't worth nuthin'. 
>
>        ADAM    You know what I mean -- the envelope with the stamps.  I want it. 
>
>        TEX (a pause, then beginning to laugh)  You greenhorn -- you half-witted, 
>        thick-skulled, hare-brained, greenhorn!  They wuz both too smart
>        for us!
>
>        ADAM    What are you talking about? 
>
>        TEX     First her husband, now her -- she hoodwinked you!  She batted 
>        all them big eyes and you went 'n fell for it - like a egg from a tall 
>        chicken!  Here! (holding out the envelope) You want? Here -- it's yours!
>      ```
>
> ADAM takes it and looks at it.
>
> 348. INSERT -- ENVELOPE The corner containing the stamps is missing, torn off.
> 349. MED. SHOT -- ADAM AND TEX TEX sees the expression on ADAM's face and begins laughing, hysterically.
>
>      ```
>        TEX     Look at you!  Horn-swoggled by a purty face'n all them sweet words!
>        You killed all three of 'em for nothin'! You greenhorn! You block-headed
>        jackass!  You clod --   -- you booby -- you nincompoop -- !
>      ```